# Can we deduce that $|z|≥|a|-|b|$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let us consider three complex numbers $z,a,b$ such that the equality $z=a-b$ holds true. Can we deduce that $$|z|≥|a|-|b|$$

Comment: Since |.| is a norm, the inequality holds (can be proved using triangle inequality).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

$$
a = b + z
$$
so
$$
|a| = |b + z| \leq |b| + |z|.
$$

In fact, even more is true! Since $b = a - z$, you can repeat this,
$$
|b| = |a - z| \leq |a| + |z|
$$

and combining these two, you have

$$
|z| \geq ||a| - |b||
$$

Answer (score 3):

Yes since by triangle inequality we have

$$|a-b|\ge|a|-|b|$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, first $z=a-b\iff z+b=a$. Then

$$|a|=|z+b|\le |z|+|b|$$

Then subtract $|b|$ from both sides.